# jQuery clicking click event not working on Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Hey all I have a unique issue that I can not seem to find a way to fixing.

This is what my data table looks like:

[image][image]

I've added the red trashcan that you currently see in the image above in order for the user to delete that row. I add this trashcan by injecting it within the datatables **createdRow**:

```
fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
   $(nRow).find('#trashIcon').attr({ 'data-indexer': (iDisplayIndex + 1) });
   $(nRow).find('#trashIcon').attr({ 'data-table': 1 });
},
createdRow: function (row, data, dataIndex) {    
   $(row).prepend('<i id="trashIcon" ' +
           'data-eventid="' + data.RequestID + '" ' +
                  'class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg grow-1" ' +
            'aria-hidden="true" ' +
                  'style="color: rgba(169, 68, 66, 1); ' +
                         'left: 3px; top: 10px; ' +
                         'position: relative; ' +
                         'z-index: 500; ' +
                         'box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(150,150,150,0.3);">' +
                  '</i>');
},
```

And after all that's said and done with the injections the HTML code looks like:

```
<table width="100%" 
       class="display cell-border dataTable no-footer" 
       id="theDT2" 
       role="grid" 
       aria-describedby="theDT2_info" 
       style="width: 100%;" 
       cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    [HEADER CODE HERE...]
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
        <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg grow-1" 
           id="trashIcon" 
           aria-hidden="true" 
           style="left: 3px; 
                               top: 10px; 
                             color: rgba(169, 68, 66, 1); 
                          position: relative; 
                        box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(150,150,150,0.3);" 
           data-eventid="976" 
           data-indexer="1" 
           data-table="2">
        </i>
        <td class="sorting_1">976</td>
        [TABLE CODE HERE]
    </tr>
</table>
```

**id="trashIcon"** is the trashcan image you see in the rows. As you see I am setting **trashcanHover** to true on the trashcan click event but that doesn't seem to **pass fast enough** to the datatables click even when I **console.log** that out - it always says false.

The jQuery code I have for clicking on the trashcan is this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#trashIcon', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    trashcanHover = true;
});
```

And this is the jQuery code for the clicking of any part of the datatables row:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    //Listens for the user to click on a data row in the table
    if (typeof $(this).attr('class') != 'undefined') {
        var tblName = $(this).closest('table').attr("ID");
        var headerClick = $(this).attr("aria-controls");

        console.log(trashcanHover);

        if (typeof $(this).attr('class') != 'undefined') {
            if (tblName == "theDT") {
                edit_person(theTable.row(this).data().RequestID);
            } else {
                edit_event(theTable2.row(this).data().EventID);
            }
        } else {
            if ($(this).data('table') == 1) {
                $('#theDT').dataTable().fnDeleteRow($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
            } else {
                $('#theDT2').dataTable().fnDeleteRow($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now if I comment out either one of those click functions then it does what it should do (either open data to edit or delete that row). What I am having issues with is that it never fully sees the trashcan click (even though I click on it with the mouse). It just fires off the datatables click row function and I can not find a way to **distinguish between the two of them** in order to do an IF THAN.

The code above does work with checking if just the headers were clicked on and if so, don't edit that row's data.

Currently though when I click on the trashcan it **does delete** that row but **also opens the edit** for that row that just got deleted.

**for Louys Patrice Bessette**

[image]

Seems to always goto the datatable's click event first...

Comment: There shouldn't be more than one unique ID per HTML page.

Comment: An `id` **MUST** be unique. Use a class to target your trash icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `class` to target elements that are created via a loop.
Because an `id` **must** be unique.

I assume this is an immediate delete row function...
So this should work:

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa-trash-o', function (e) {
    // To stop the click propagation up to the `tr` handler
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Delete the row.
    $('#theDT2').dataTable().fnDeleteRow($(this).closest('tr')[0]);
});
```

---

**EDIT**
okay... Let's try something else then.

In the `tr` handler, add:

```
$(document.body).on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    if(e.target.className.split(" ")[1]=="fa-trash-o"){
        return;
    }
    // rest of your code...
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. Still goes to the datatable click event - deletes the row then opens up the edit.

Comment: I just improved it... Since there is more than one class to it. Should work now.